# Is it possible to execute javascript in a UIWebView via UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

As the title says, I would like to execute some javascript within a UIWebView through the UIAutomation console.   Can this be done?  I'm assuming it *should* be possible but I cannot find any documentation or really anything related to how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible. `UIAWebView` does not expose an evaluate method like `UIWebView` does. You can however click a link: `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].webViews()[0].links()["Say Hello"].tap();` Just tried to record a script with Instruments to see what's possible.